# MeteorJS and sockjs closing connection even with a fresh install

Tags: mongodb, meteor, sockjs, ddp

I've been having a persistent issue with Meteor recently, I keep getting this error in the Chrome after starting any application.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/679/1mdsxflf/websocket' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response    ddp.js:1344
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

I thought that something had gone wrong in my upgrade of Meteor so I uninstalled it completely and tried a fresh install.

I created the Todos example, started it up and I still get the same problem.

[image: Meteor SockJS Connection Failed]

This is with a fresh MeteorJS install.

This also affects the Hot Code Push, so if I was developing I would have to force a refresh from the browser to see my changes.

I'm open for any ideas, even wiping out /usr/local or other files that could be affecting this.

Comment: I'd clear the browser cache. Did you check if you have the same problem in Firefox?

Comment: It's not the cache, I've cleared it before this posting. The problem also occurs in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: @Don do you use a proxy on your machine?

Comment: @Akshat I don't, minus the proxy that meteor sets up when running the `meteor` command.

Comment: Also the error indicates that the server fails already at the handshake, does it maybe still send something which could give a clue? You could (maybe) see that in the Network tab of the Chrome Dev Tools when you click on websocket there and watch at the Frames. Or (safer) look at the raw traffic with Wireshark.

Comment: As an experiment, I set up a vagrant box and got meteor up and running and everything works there. So there is something with my machine that is causing this hiccup.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?